# How to load a different html.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I'm trying to use mytheme_preprocess_html() to load a different **html.html.twig** file based on certain conditions (GET variables in URL).

In D7 I've done the this with:

```
if (isset($_GET['response_type']) && $_GET['response_type'] == 'embed') {
    $variables['template_file'] = 'raw';
}
```

Where *variables['template_file'] = 'raw';* set the name of the tpl file to load (raw.tpl.php). It works fine.

Now I need to do the same thing in D8, but I can't find the way.
I tried:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) { 
    if (isset($_GET['response_partial']) && $_GET['response_partial'] == 'header') {
        $variables['html']['#theme'] = 'raw';
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

**Edit**

I know how to set different template for page.html.twig, but I can't figure out how to do the same for the file html.html.twig

The function

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) { 
    $suggestions[] = 'html__raw';
    $suggestions[] = 'page__header'; }
```

Works properly for the page template but not for the html.

Comment: I don't think my question is a duplicate of the linked thread. I have edited my original question to underline the fact I'm trying to usa a different html.html.twig not the page.html.twig file.

Comment: Did you actually rename your function to `mytheme_theme_suggestions_html_alter()`? Do not forget that this is an implementation of [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x), meaning that the "HOOK" part must match the name of your template.